# Adldap: Eloquent Query, "where not in group"

Tags: laravel, eloquent, active-directory, adldap

I have a query where I'm returning an awful lot of rows, so need to limit which fields I'm calling back, so I'm using `select` and a where method.

However I also would like to limit it further by ignoring those in certain groups.

I currently have

```
$users = Adldap::search()
            ->select('extensionattribute2', 'mail', 'samaccountname')
            ->where('company', '=', $company)
            ->get();
```

Can someone help me add a where clause so that I can only select users from that aren't in a selection of 4 groups.

EG. Select all users, but not those in "Accounts", "HR", "Admins".

Comment: What is the name of the field where `"Accounts","HR"` exists ?

Answer (score 0):

> Well you can write `whereNotIn` for this case. For quick answer I am assuming that you have a database field which is `group_name` which includes `"Accounts", "HR", "Admins"`. It's just for clarifying to you. You can change your database field name.

```
$users = Adldap::search()
        ->select('extensionattribute2', 'mail', 'samaccountname')
        ->where('company', '=', $company)
        ->whereNotIn('group_name', ["Accounts", "HR", "Admins"])
        ->get();
```

---

*This query will return all users ignoring `"Accounts", "HR", "Admins"`*

Comment: This didn't work for me.  It instead tried to do a search against the field NotIn

Comment: What's your issue dear ?

Answer (score 0):

use whereDoesntHave:

```
$unwantedGroups=["Accounts", "HR", "Admins"];
$users=Adldap::search()->whereDoesntHave('groups',function (Builder $query) use($unwantedGroups){
    $query->whereIn('groupName', $unwantedGroups)
})->select('extensionattribute2', 'mail', 'samaccountname')
->where('company', '=', $company)->get();
```

please be careful about relation name between user & groups 'groups or group'.

more details in:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-wherein

Comment: This also didn't work for me, tries to search the field "doesnt_have" array:3 [
   "field" => "doesnt_have"
   "operator" => "="
   "value" => "\64\69\73\74\69\6e\67\75\69\73\68\65\64\6e\61\6d\65"
 ]